# Why are my Google APIs not installing properly to Android Studio AVD? Red iconed

Tags: android-studio, google-api, android-virtual-device

AVD won't run many API levels on the virtual device. But I installed the APIs in the SDK Manager. They are also shown as installed but in the `Extras`-Folder, they have this red icon, which you can see here in the Screenshot

[image: here in the Screenshot]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by wrong/missing `source.properties` file for example: my Google API 23 was the same and it was missing

*source.properties*

```
### Android Tool: Source of this archive.
#Fri Aug 19 04:03:37 CEST 2016
Addon.NameDisplay=Google APIs
Addon.NameId=google_apis
Addon.VendorDisplay=Google Inc.
Addon.VendorId=google
AndroidVersion.ApiLevel=23
Pkg.Desc=Android + Google APIs
Pkg.License=Terms and Conditions.... (here was licence but I removed it because it was too big)
Pkg.LicenseRef=android-sdk-license
Pkg.Revision=1
Pkg.SourceUrl=https\://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
```

The easy way to repair it is to delete packages and install them again, but first check if it works, because it is possible that the package is fine.

Comment: Deleting and re-installing packages did not resolve the issue

Comment: Do you have good source.properties files? If not then download this pack and put it into your SDK https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwVbx1E4ikgUM1dTTVpVWGQ4Zjg/view?usp=sharing  I would also try downloading SDK manager again from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads under *Get just the command line tools*

Comment: The bounty time is up and I have to award points but I have not resolved the issue so will pass out points so best possible answers at least get points. I will try and resolve with these answers.

Comment: PS where should the source.properties file be? Is it different for each API? Sorry I know nothing of this.

Comment: It is a little bit different for each API and it should be located like: `D:\AndroidSDK\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-15\source.properties`

Answer (score 1):

You missing the base api level of particular google api as per your screenshot.
refer to this for more info http://tools.android.com/recent/sdkmanagerfixes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run your emulator?...seems like it's a **display bug in Android SDK manager**. Am also getting the same broken image error display but my emulators all are working fine.[image: SDK manager]

Comment: No, the emulators with the red icon do not work but those without them do work. Odd...